# visual studio - strange error on extension method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods

```
Error   1335    The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'Wedding.Helpers.ModelStateExtensions.GetFirstErrorMessage(System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary)' and 
'Wedding.Helpers.ModelStateExtensions.GetFirstErrorMessage(System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary)'    
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\scratch\Archant\WebSites\Weding\Areas\AddressBook\Controllers\Partner\HomeController.cs 
31  69  Wedding
```

it's pointing to the exact same method on the conflict!!

Why oh why?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282636/the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or-properties-bug/1282640#1282640

Comment: i don't have an App_Code folder :(

Comment: may be your project reference to self!

Comment: arrrrr that was it!! how did that happen!!! thanks dude

Comment: bung it as an answer an i'll mark it correct. even though it makes me look totally noddy :)

Comment: embroglio! my intent is my programing divagations not you

Answer (score 1):

Where are you creating the Helper class?

If it's in the App_Code folder..that's probably the issue.
Here's a previous answer with more details:

[The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties (bug??)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282636/the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or-properties-bug)

Comment: i don't have an App_Code folder :( –