# The call is amibiguous - same signature, single method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a brand new MVC5 project, I have a single html helper:

```
public static IHtmlString Localized(this HtmlHelper html, string url)
{
    return /* code here */
}
```

In an empty page, I attempt to call this:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Home Page"; }
@Html.Localized("~/content/images/mobile/hero.png");
```

And I get this error:

CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'EUCA.HtmlHelpers.Localized(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)' and 'EUCA.HtmlHelpers.Localized(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)'

How is one method conflicting with itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered here:
[The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties (bug??)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282636/the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or-properties-bug)

App_Code causes the code to be compiled twice, which doesn't seem to cause a problem in some basic cases. Extension methods an edge case that does not work with App_Code.