# Publish Web dialog for a standard VS Website Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Until I started building MVC sites, I always built WebForm web sites using Visual Studio *Web Site* projects (instead of *Web Application* projects).  When I publish my MVC sites, I'm loving the Publish Web dialog that allows much more control over the deployment than I'm used to.  This is the feature I've been looking for for 5 years!  Web Site projects only allow one fairly brutal mode of publishing.

I'm curious:

1. Is this an MVC feature, or is it
   available for all Web Application
   projects?
2. Is there any way to get
   this dialog to appear when
   publishing a Web Site project?
3. Has publishing of Web Site projects
   improved in the VS 2010 Beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's available for all Web Application projects.
2. No.  Web site projects are generally meant to be used for "in place" web sites, or for smaller sites where you want them to be updateable on the fly.  They're really a bad option in a lot of ways when you're talking about deployment.  You should check out [this pretty famous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application) here on Stackoverflow for a lot of commentary on this topic.
3. I believe there are a number of new deployment options for VS2010, although I haven't heard much about Website Projects.  [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/02/04/web-deployment-with-vs-2010-and-iis.aspx) from the dev team details several new deployment tools for Web Application Projects.

Comment: Thanks.  When VS 2005 came out, it seemed like Web Site projects were the way forward, and they were a lot easier the VS 2003 web projects.  I guess that's not the case anymore!