# Class Library Project VS App_Code - Pros / Cons?

Tags: asp.net, class-library, app-code

I currently use the App_Code folder for all of my classes, and for me (for now) it seems to be working just fine.

I have however been considering making the switch over to a Class Library Project inside my Solution instead of the App_Code folder.  Can anyone tell me the pros and cons of doing this?

One thought I had was with regards to testing my web app.  If I use a Class Library, do I have to compile it every time I want to tweak/test? Obviously in the App_Code folder I don't have to since all of the Classes compile at runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a class library.  The reasons are simple.

You want to remove your business or application logic from the UI.  The App_Code folder is for classes that deal with the UI only.

The reason for the separation is to create tiers.  Meaning today you have a web site, tommorow you may be asked to make a windows program, or a new web site.  If you have to change your UI you are going to be copying and pasting the code.  That means you have now 2 or more places to maintain the code.  This will lead to poorer code quality, fixing the same bug in 2 or more places.

If you place your code in a library.  You create a new UI and then just reference the library.  You are only now using 1 set of code.

Comment: This is a great answer, and one that makes perfect sense.  In my question above I mentioned having to compile the Class Library over and over while testing... is there a way around this?

Comment: So the answer is that I have to compile it every time I make a tweak or mod?

Comment: You don't have to compile the business logic if you haven't changed it.  Compiling does not take that much time and is not a good reason to keep all your code in your UI layer.

Answer (score 0):

[Jimmy Bogard](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/12/08/organizing-asp-net-mvc-solutions.aspx) (author of Automapper) has written an excellent [article](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/12/08/organizing-asp-net-mvc-solutions.aspx) on how he structures his code, which may assist in confirming @David's answer.