# ASP.NET Website vs ASP.NET WebApp: What's the performance difference?

Tags: asp.net, performance

The [Difference between an ASP.NET Website and ASP.NET Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application) has been asked many times. However, I couldn't find an answer to my question as to whether there is any real performance difference in using one over the other. Further, it is my understanding that a website project is dynamically compiled; does that means every time a request compiles the requested page?

Comment: Dont you think the question title is a bit confusing?

Comment: Not everytime. Just the first one after it's been changed.

Comment: Or at the next request after the app pool recycles.

Answer (score 4):

Let's make assumptions here and anyone who made actual tests can add their two cents.

### Application start speed difference

Website start:

- Website has less code to compile => faster
- Website has to compile + JIT compile => double work

Web application start:

- Only has to JIT compile => single work
- Has to compile the whole assembly (or several of them for that matter) => slower, since there's more code to compile

### Running application speed difference

When all pages of a website have been accessed, there shouldn't be any speed difference any more. No compiles happen and code just runs. In this regard, both type of Asp.net apps are the same.

### Code changes differentiation

Website:

- changing a particular file slows things down just for that particular file, because it has to compile + JIT compile it again

Webapplication:

- any change means recompiling the whole assembly, which means more JIT compiling on the server.

Answer (score 1):

For an asp.net website the pages are compiled dynamically as needed.  AKA - the first time they are accessed or when they change.

I think the performance difference is minor/not at all different after compile between the two solutions.  The two solutions are designed for different needs/desires.

By being dynamically compiled you can put a new code behind file on the server and it will recognize the new file and recompile when the next person accesses it.  This gives flexibility in updating your site.

However, a web application has many advantages over a website.  See this [blog post](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/08/web-application-project-vs-web-site.html) for and [this one](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/02/07/web-site-vs-web-application) for a nice comparison of the two.