# Web.config Transformations in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, configuration, web.config-transform

How can I perform web.config transformations using Visual Studio 2008?

Someone had asked me if you can perform config transformations in Visual Studio 2008. I know you can as I do remember several articles on this. However, I can't seem to find any of the links as of now. Can anyone point to an article on Google/Bing/Search of the week and/or provide a quick sample so that I may pass it on?

Everything I'm finding targets 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

**Visual Studio 2008:** http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/02/17/ASPNET-40-Part-4-Config-Transformation-Files.aspx

Via:

http://www.google.com/search?&rlz=&q=%22config+transformation+visual+in+visual+studio+2008%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=#sclient=psy&hl=de&q=web.config+transformation+in+visual+studio+2008&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=1&cad=b

---

**Visual Studio 2010:** [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621010228/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx)

Via:

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=web.config+transformation+vs2010#sclient=psy&hl=de&source=hp&q=web.config+transformation+vs2010&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=web.config+transformation+vs2010&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=8ba42b7f45bd826&cad=b

Comment: The link you provided actually targets VS 2010.

Comment: You're right. That happens when you're not careful enough. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. On the US version of Google, I didn't see that. It's quite frustrating.

Comment: Is there any info on how to do this in VS2008? Is it even Possible? None of the above links reference VS2008.

Comment: Can you summarize the solution and use the link as a reference? I know the question originally asked for this, but it would be a much better answer if it weren't link only. The top link is broken as well.