# Does Visual Studio 2008 has Web.config.Debug and Web.Config.Release for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-config

As titled, does it? I am pretty sure I saw it in Visual Studio 2010. (I don't have Visual Studio 2010 in the office...)

I want to have debug mode use debug server connection string etc.

If not, any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 has `web.config` transforms, which use `web.debug.config` and `web.release.config` files to apply transformations to the original `web.config`. It actually uses whatever the current build configuration name is; Debug and Release are the defaults, of course.

One important note is that this is a Visual Studio feature, *not* an IIS feature. IIS won't pay any attention to a web.[anything].config file; only the real one.

Also, the transforms are *not* used while running the web application within Visual Studio: Transforms are applied during building a deployment package, and the output web.config has the proper transforms applied.

[MSDN: How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx)

Comment: +1 Thanks, didn't know it called Web.config transformation and works in that way. Now I could able to find solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024401/web-config-transformations-in-vs2008