# Editing the Web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have an ASP.NET website (not web application) and I publish it using the 'publish' option (to five Windows Servers (2003)).

My development PC contains version 11 of Oracle (DataAccess.dll) and the web servers use version 10.  I cannot downgrade my development machine because it has Windows 7 and this is incompatible with version 10.  I cannot upgrade the server to version 11 because whilst Windows Server 2003 is compatible it doesn't seem to work very well with Oracle 11.  I have ensured that the server is patched up.

Therefore when publishing the website I have the following line in the web.config:

```
<add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=10.2.0.100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342"/>
```

Then once the web app is published, I manually change the web.config.  Is there an automated way of doing this, perhaps using the build scripts? Would it help if I converted into a web application?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is web.config transformation available in Visual Studio 2010.

You can find "how to" [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @jrummell yes it does, it is a bit trickier though [Using Web.config Transformation in Web Site Projects](http://andrewtwest.com/2010/02/25/using-web-config-transformations-in-web-site-projects/)

Comment: @DZL, is there a solution for visual studio 2008?

Comment: @w0051977 I haven't tried it with vs2008 but here is a similar question that might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024401/web-config-transformations-in-vs2008

Comment: @DZL, I have downloaded WDP.  Can you specify what I should specify in web config section replacements for add assembly?

Comment: @w0051977 What have you come up with so far? Edit the question to include that information. You should create something like AppSettings.config and and AppSettings.Live.config and use it in a web.config like <add assembly="AppSettings.config"/> and <add assembly="AppSettings.Live.config"/>

Comment: Thanks, the like was quite useful.  +1.  Are you able to answer my other deployment question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244028/net-microsoft-common-targets-namespace?