# Global conditional define (#const) statements in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, conditional-compilation

Is there a way to define a conditional define, i.e. #const, in a asp/vb.net app that it accessible across multiple source files?

I want to use, for example,

```
#const useOracle=TRUE
```

but to be able to change it's value in only one place.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the project properties (right-click the project in the Solution Explorer, select "Properties"), in the "Compile" tab. Click the "Advanced Compiler Options" button, and enter your constants into the "Custom constants" text box.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think I was a little unclear - the project is an ASP.net project - I can't see anywhere to enter custom constants on the property pages, but I'm sure I must be missing something.

Comment: @Bob: If you have created an "ASP.NET Web Application" project it should work as described above, if you have an "ASP.NET Web Site" project , I don't know any way to do it. Also, if you have a "web site" project, make sure this is what you really want: [ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

Comment: Thanks, interesting link. Unfortunately, I am developing a web *site* and I'd have to check, but I think this may be a mandatory requirement for where the site will be hosted.