# What is the difference between a simple ASP.Net website and ASP.Net webapplication?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

In Visual Studio, I tried a project in both. But there appears to be no difference in the tools displayed in the tool box....

So what the real basic major difference.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Website is for internet based audience - in this case your [concerns(security, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site) are different;
- Web application is a software, just like a desktop application software, *usually* intended to be used for **intranet** environments. For instance, an HR software could be a web app - that is available on the intranet for all the departments to fill in their timesheets.

Though, a website may contain specific operations, tasks, or workflows.

Checkout: [Web site project vs Web app project](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/08/web-application-project-vs-web-site.html)

Answer (score 3):

See these:

[ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

WebSite project is compiled on the fly.

In a WebApplication, you need to build a page before you can debug.

However, WebApplication is the way to go, because with WebSite-project, you cannot create a setup project (and conversion from WebSite to WebApplication can lead to problems/bugs).

That's why I recommend WebApplication. 
Simply put, a WebSite is worth nothing if the customer is too stupid to install it manually.