# Is my Visual Studio project a web application or a web site?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

First of all, when to use what and the overall differences between them has already been answered before. But I couldn't find an answer to this question:

> Where can I check if my Visual Studio project is a Web Application or a Web Site?

Comment: To be perfectly blunt I'm not aware of any major difference. What would that difference be, in your view? THe only thing I can come up with is that a site is something on your _webserver_ (that you can browse) which is after deploying (perhaps from Visual Studio). I have a feeling I'm missing your point though...

Comment: Web Site uses the .cs files, Web Application gets built into .DLL and run from there.

Comment: Do the *Solution Explorer* inside VS contain the exact same files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally, one tell tale sign for me is whether the project folder actually contains a project file, or not.

You can see the icons differ slightly in VS - a web application has a layered `world->docs->language` icon and a web site just consists of `world->docs`.

Also, once opened within VS, right-clicking will display `Properties` and `Property Pages` for web applications and web sites respectively; further, on clicking this option you will be greeted with a dialog for the former and MDI tabbed form for the latter - the latter also exposes more functionality to control pre and post build steps and so forth.

A a web application will also display `Properties` and `References` *special folders* as part of the project tree in the Solution Explorer, whereas a web site does not necessarily; unless manually created for some reason (but they still won't be *special* - web sites use the `bin` folder for their references).

Comment: A Web Site project will have a "My Project" file but a Web Application won't?

Comment: I agree with the project file. A web application has Project File in Properties window. A web site doesn't.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to differentiate between Web Site and Web Application is to look at the project's icons.

*Web Site*

- has an icon without the used language
- displays its physical root path
- does not have a Properties folder

[image: Web Site]

*Web Application*

- has an icon including the used language
- displays the project's name
- has a Properties folder

[image: Web Application]

To find out more about the technical differences between them ...

[ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

Answer (score 3):

I recently found out (painfully) that web applications do not support Profiles which is not fun. Web sites however do support them and make life much easier. I noticed here people saying there are no major differences. This one is quite major and can make your life difficult if you select to make a web application instead of a web site.

Answer (score 0):

`Web application` and `Web Site` are VS templates, nothing more. I doubt you will find this information directly somewhere in project. You can try to go through template differences list and guess how this particular project was created.

Answer (score 0):

For Web Site project, once run (F5) you can change the code in the code-behind, the solution will allow it and it will compile on the fly when saved.

A Web Application project, however, will not allow this. This is the simplest way of being able to tell between the two.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought there would be an easier way than this =/ ?

Comment: A Web Site deployment will have .cs files, whereas a Web Application will not - this is another way to tell. But the above solution only takes 20 seconds to do.