# How to check if my project is a website or a webapp in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web

How do i check if my project is considered as a website or a webapp?

Initially when i create my project, i select empty web application but somehow i got a feeling that it is becoming like a website.

I have searched this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403221/is-my-visual-studio-project-a-web-application-or-a-web-site) which explain how to differentiate while in Visual Studio 2010 but not in Visual Studio 2012.

Can someone kindly enlighten me on how to differentiate between these two ?

Comment: Read MSDN - [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple just right click on the project if you see **Property Pages** in the popup menu then its website and if you see **Properties** then its web app

Comment: wow, its really that simple? this answer was remarkably hard to find. My google-foo must be off.
I think what confuses me is that my solution has several projects, only one of which is the "start up" project and given your answer, its a site, not an app, but the other projects appear to be apps. See how I confused things there? ;)