# Visual Studio 2008, Why is App_code missing from .NET folders

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

New to working with Visual Studio Solutions.

I normally place my Site Class file with basic functions in a folder called App_code

But noticed I created a website project in visual studio and only have options for .net folders :

App_Globalresources
App_localresources
Themes
App_Data
App_Browsers

Should I instead put my customer class files in one of these ?

Comment: Are you sure that you create a web site project not a web application?

Comment: Hey you are correct I created a ASP.NET web application. Ok Should I have created New Website instead ?

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application/398049#398049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website project can use App_Code.

Web Application project doesnt use App_Code.  You can just add a class.  Everythign compiles as code and makes a dll file.

Comment: Ok saw that above. Which do you recommend for website then, create as Web Site Project or Web Application ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(v=vs.80).aspx#wapp_topic5   I typically use web application projects.  But one of the advantages of website project is the actual code files are copied to the hosting and it's easier to make code changes to a production side.  With web application project everything compiles and you copy the dll files.  If you have a larget solution with several projects web application project is better.