# Is it possible to use the Web Application project and make changes without having to recompile/redeploy the whole project?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application) post, but I do not think it really answered my question.  I realize that the *Web Site project* is best(?) to use if you want to be able to make changes to the web site and deploy, say, User Controls/pages, without having to recompile and deploy the whole site.

However, is this possible to do with the Web Application project as well? What about Web Application and Web Deployment project options?  I basically have a high traffic web site and I want to make changes without having to force redeployment of the whole site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically whilst deploying Web Application using Visual Studio it redeploying only the changed files, so do not worry about that.

[ASP.NET Web Application Project Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx)

> If you use one-click publish to deploy your application to a
>   third-party hosting company, the hosting company will typically
>   provide you with the settings that you require for the Publish Profile
>   dialog box.
>
> When you have finished specifying publish settings, you can click the
>   Publish button in this dialog box or in the Web One Click Publish
>   toolbar. Visual Studio then deploys the application on the destination
>   computer. When you click the Publish button after a Web application
>   project has already been deployed, Visual Studio redeploys only the
>   changed items.