# ASP.NET using DLL's instead of App_Code

Tags: asp.net

What are the advantages, if there are any, of using a separate DLL in the BIN folder instead of adding your classes to the App_Code folder. Is there a method preferred?

Comment: maybe this will help you understand why: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtba4t8b(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this article [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) on MSDN.
You can also read anserws from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)