# Where to put the customized profile provider in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, profile

Should the FactoredProfileProvider.cs be placed in App_Code only? What is the standard way to do it? Can I put it under an Area that handles all accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the FactoredProfileProvider.cs be placed in App_Code only?

Absolutely not. The `App_Code` folder should never be used with the web applications model which is what ASP.NET MVC uses. This folder is used only with websites. See web [application vs website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application). So in ASP.NET MVC you could place this file wherever you want, like for example you could create yourself a subfolder called `ProfileProviders` and put it inside.

Comment: Is it possible to put the provider in a class library? And of course, we need to copy all the connection string and related settings from web.config into the new app.config in the class library.

Comment: @Blaise you wouldn't copy the settings into an app.config for a class library, they won't be used at runtime. The main applications config is used.

Comment: @Blaise, of course that you can put the provider in a seprate class library but as Adam said, there's no such thing as app.config for a class library. The settings must remain in the main application configuration file which in the case of ASP.NET MVC is the web.config.