# The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a wcf service hosted in a website in IIS and I seem to have this issue.
In my web.config I have this:

```
<system.web>
        <compilation>
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
```

All projects in the solution target framework 4.0.

LE: I get the error when I try to import System.Linq;

```
 using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Please post the code where the error is occurring.

Comment: FYI, it's generally a bad idea to use web site "projects" for WCF services (or anything other than fairly simple web sites).

Comment: actually, it's a fairly simple web site :)

Comment: @JohnSaunders Do you mean web application projects?  I was under the impression web site projects were preferred for larger sites.  Could you cite a reference?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application seems to indicate there are pros and cons to both.

Comment: Web sites are not projects. They are unique in that they do not build. They have many unique problems that no other Visual Studio "project" type has, including strange things happening with namespace recognition. If you must use a web site "project" for your actual site,then at least use a web application project for your services. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Don't edit your answer into the question. Post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @gigi If specifying the `targetFramework` attribute fixed your problem, then either a higher level web.config specified a different target version, or your IIS application pool is incorrectly configured.  I would check your app pool first.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The only thing preventing adoption of *web projects* over *"web-sites"* is that with a *"web-project"* all the code is compiled into assembly dlls; rather than having original source code on the web-server.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution: It seems that the web config should be:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: You also need to add `using System.Linq`

Comment: I found I had 2 `<system.web>` tags in my `web.config`, removing one of them did the trick.

Comment: @HüseyinYağlı He did have `using System.Linq`. That was the error.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a code file in your site with either `Imports System.Linq` (VB) or `using System.Linq;` (c#)?

Seems like the simplest answer is that it is a typo.  Maybe the namespace should be corrected to `System.Data.Linq`.

Edit:
System.Linq should be a valid namespace, as it "provides classes and interfaces that support queries that use Language-Integrated Query (LINQ)." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx).  It is also imported by default in the system-level web.config.

So, not sure what is happening here if it is not related to my suggestion above.  Maybe something wrong in your machine.config or system-level web.config?

Edit 2:
I find it strange that you adding the System.Core assembly at this level.  I believe this is the assembly that includes the System.Linq namespace.  Maybe removing it would help?

Edit 3:
`System.Linq` is imported by default in the machine-level web.config.  You can remove the line in your code file.

Comment: System.Linq is a namespace but it is in System.Core.dll assembly, which i referenced, damn this is strange.

Comment: @gigi yeah this is a strange one.  Did this start out as a 3.5 project or something?  And, just to clarify:  Is it a web SITE project or web APPLICATION project?

Comment: Removing System.Core is not helping, it is a web site and all the projects from the application are developed in .net 4.0 ( all started in .net 4.0 )

Comment: @gigi I suggest removing the import line in your code file.  It shouldn't be necessary anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it "disappears" just for the fun of it. If you don't need it just delete it.

Else right click your website in the solution explorer and add a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

I had no Linq methods on my Controller (Count, Where, toList, etc...). Adding the namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

fixed the problem for me. Maybe will help someone in the future...

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that Visual Studio was too dumb to find this namespace by itself when "ctrl + ." on the compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding the `System.Linq` namespace to the namespaces in the `Views\Shared\Web.config` file, e.g, as below, 2nd from the bottom, above the `WebApplication1` namespace.

*Note, this is in the `Web.config` in the `Views` folder and is not the web site's main 'Web.config`.*

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Linq" />
            <add namespace="WebApplication1" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is is your .csproj file, specifically these items:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile47</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

If you don't have a folder for the Profile indicated, you might need to manually change it to one you do have. You might also be able to download the target from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks.

Unfortunately, my colleague had this happen with an old-style PCL project ([profile-based PCL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#comparison-to-portable-class-libraries)), so he wasn't able to go download the .NET Portable target, but I had to give him the DLLs out of my functioning folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile47).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you didn't add

```
debug="true|false" targetFramework="4.0"
```

in compilation tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but my web app was running on framework v2.0.  Changed my application pool from v2.0 to v4.0. all working...happy days

Comment: Do you have any link or reference to this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to:

1. Go to: Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
2. Install the **System.Linq** package.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the hidden **.vs** folder and restarting Visual Studio fixed it for me.