# Linq does not exist in the namespace System

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, visual-studio

I am trying to run an asp.net application that has been created in Visual Studio 2013 in Visual Studio 2015, but I am having a lot of build errors. All errors are in the two website projects and can be traced back to the following error:

> CS0234    The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

All projects are being build using .net4.0 or higher, but still I recieve this error. When the project is build in vs2013 everything builds fine.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

Does someone know what could be wrong here?

Comment: Add reference of System.Linq and System.Data.Linq

Comment: Dupe?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070501/the-type-or-namespace-name-linq-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system

Comment: What references are present under the `<compilation>` block?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in Configuration file.

```
<compilation debug="false">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: I have added these, cleaned the solution and rebuild the solution, but it did not help.

Answer (score -3):

You could try adding;

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

To your Web.Config file.

Comment: Isn't `System.Data.Linq` the LINQ to SQL library, that was deprecated 6 years ago?