# How to register an HttpModule that is not in the App_code folder

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I would like to have my code for an HttpModule somewhere else than in the App_code folder, is that possible?

EDIT: For now, i have my module in a class file in the App_code folder of my web application. I'm successfuly registering it with this line in my web.config

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="myModule" type="myModule,App_code"/>
</httpModules>
```

What i would like to do is being able to put my class file somewhere else than in the Ape_code folder. Something like :

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="myModule" type="myModule, myOtherFolder"/>
</httpModules>
```

Comment: Please start with [google/documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) and come back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: First result on Google for your title http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

Comment: You haven't indicated what you've tried or what information you've reviewed.

Comment: Ho why thank you for the link you gave me (twice). I guess i never saw it (every single google search i did myself had this link at some point), and it doesn't help me. I'll add more details as to why it doen'st help.

Comment: You'll want to do some searching on the proper use of "namespaces" so that you can reference the code correctly in the config file.

Comment: I followed that namespace lead, and tried <add name="myModule" type="myNamespace.myModule, myApplicationAssemblyName"/> while putting my httpmodule class inside the said namespace. Still no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, finaly, here's how I solved my problem. I found that to register an HttpModule, you have to use the foollowing syntax.

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="MyModuleName" type="MyApplicationNamespace.MyModuleNamespace.MyModuleClassName, MyApplicationAssemblyName"/>
</httpModules>
```

Notes:

- MyModuleName is not restrictive, it is used by the application to reference the module
- Since MyApplicationName and MyApplicationAssemblyName is often the same (it is in my case), it is probable that the syntax above isn't totaly acurate.

Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  You'll have to switch from "Web Site Project" to "Web Application Project."  Here are a few resources to get you started:

[Walkthrough: Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

[Introduction to Web Application Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/398037/475820)

Comment: I believe i'm already working with a web application project.

Comment: Web Application Projects don't have an App_Code folder by default.  It was either added manually by somebody or the project was converted from a Web Site Project.  Either way, the resources referenced here should shed some light on what you want to do.

Comment: I added the folder myself because in the exemples i read, it was where i should put my httpModule class file. What i want is being able to put the class file somewhere else.