# Web application project vs web site project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

I just wanted to get advice on which one I should use and why?  Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=web+application+vs+web+site

Comment: You migt have tried a search first. Look on the right side in the "Related Links" section.

Answer (score 1):

There is a topic on this in the MSDN Library:
[MSDN Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)