# Should I choose to create new website, or create new project in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

I created a 47 page website in VS before, using the template that comes with VS 2010.  I'm about to create a new website.  It's going to be a lead-generating website so it shouldn't really be more than 7 or 8 pages max.

I want to use **one of the online templates** that come with visual studio, although I know nothing about AJAX, or MVC, etc. I really just want a different look than the template that comes with VS.

When I open Visual Studio 2010, should click **new project**, or **new website**?  Or should I click **new website**, then **add new project**?

I'm also more familiar with VB than I am with C#.  I'll have to add a form where clients can submit information.  What would be the best route to go for a semi-remedial programmer like myself?

Comment: John, I think the question is very different than the one provided with the link you suggested.  I'm looking for different things, and my programming level doesn't appear to be near the level of the person who asked the question in the link you provided.  I'm looking to use one of the VS online templates.  And, as Cawas suggests in that link, "And nobody answered specifically about VS2010 ... Because, as a beginner, I do believe the answer is at least a little different".

Comment: Web Project if you plan on using libraries and referencing user controls across libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can actually change from one type to another so it's not such a big decision.

I'd go with new website if I were you as it doesn't sound like you will be adding other assemblies.