# Which type of project do I choose

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am going to create a solution which will have 2 projects as a class library, one project as a Web Application or Web Site.

I have gone through the differences between Web Application and Web Site at
[Microsoft : Web Application VS. Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

After reading it, I found that I need features from both of them, such as features in Web Application:

1. run unit tests on code
2. I want control over the assembly name and version number that is generated for the site.
3. I want to avoid putting source code on a production server.
4. I want to use the automated deployment tools that are available in Visual Studio 2010.

features in Web Site which I need

1. open the production site in Visual Studio and update it in real time by using FTP.
2. be able to update individual files in production by just copying new versions to the production server, or by editing the files directly on the production server.
3. be able to update individual ASP.NET Web pages (.aspx files) without having to recompile the entire Web site.

And I don't want to keep the source code on the production server due to the security concern.

And I still cannot make my decision.

I am looking for some strong reasons which can convince me to go with one of the type.

Thanks in advance.

PS:
Dear all, please provide reasons about why you marked it down, otherwise it's not going to help. Many thanks.

Comment: Dear all, please provide reasons about why you marked it down, otherwise it's not going to help.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely don't want the source on the production server, then you really have to use a Web Application Project.

A Web Site Project is generally uploaded to the server as source.

Comment: @Andres, if I choose Web Application, are there anything different from a Website when I am going to publish it online?

Comment: @Franva the differences are covered pretty well in the MSDN you attached. This is probably the most useful comparison between the two that I know of, particularly the table. Honestly I'm not sure why Microsoft even give you two options - to me it only adds confusion. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application.