# VS 2010 - How to add project properties window

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I feel really stupid, but for a new VS2010 ASP.Net web site, how do I add a Properties item under the project?  The one which you can double-click to bring up the Properties page which has the properties, application, web, settings, and other tabs along the left side?
Thanks...

Comment: You can't; the web site projects don't have the same property pages as the web application projects. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx for a list of all the differences.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application

Answer (score 0):

Yup. For that you need to have a website project NOT a websie.