# Can a Webproject Control Web Sites

Tags: asp.net

I am in the process of developing a web based solution do replace an application we provide.  The web application is a record storing application and each client would have different forms they would input data into and store.  My question is:  Is it possible to create a backbone Web Project, which would have minimal updates this would be like a container and be the same for all of our clients, and have the document forms which would be different among clients and need to be updated more often.

Any constructive comments for or against this with reason why would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you’re describing is a multi-tenant system if you'd like to do some research on that term. Your web interface remains the same for all, but the records/documents are different for each client. It sounds like you might need login/access functionality that ties the records to a client ID (possibly stored in a database). According to how you intend to store the records (file system vs. database), you can control access either based on the client ID (foreign key to the doc tables) or you might want to create roles. This is a very high overview for what can become complex according to the specs.

Comment: Thank you for the information I did know about multi tenant systems and I learned alot about what I am planning to do.  I wanted to know if people commonly used webprojects to access websites or should I write the entire thing as a website.  I want it to be secure and effecient.  Most of the tenants will not have more than 20 concurrent user.

Comment: I almost alway use a web application and put my data layer in a separate project under the same solution. For more on this see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application