# Why I can't create an object of UC in WebSites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an Asp.net Website in which there's a `user control(uc_cart.ascx)` and a `webpage(checkout.aspx)`, I want to create an object of `uc_cart.ascx` in `checkout.aspx` but I can't do this it simply doesn't shows up in intellisence box, But when I do same thing in Web Application I can.

After a while I noticed that I have to register that UC in my webpage using `<%@ Register %>` , only after that I can access that class and can create an object of the same in Website but in Web Applications I don't have to do that.

So basically **what are the major differences between a Website and a Web Application ?**

and **Why can't I create that object with out that**`<%@ Register %>` **block ?**

Answer (score 1):

Use `LoadControl` method to instantiate the Web User control.

```
Control control=LoadControl("~/uc_cart.ascx");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);
```

Reference Links:

1. [MSDN - Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)
2. [StackOverflow  - ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

Comment: My requirements were a little different, But question isn't about how can I create that object question is WHY I can't with out that `<%@ Register %>` ?

Comment: @yogi - No need to `<%@ Register %>` a control if you're creating a control dynamically using `LoadControl` method.

Comment: Actually I was finding that control in Master page and creating an object of that control in my webpage, But I guess the code that you have provided will create a new object of that control. What should I do in this case ?