# ASP.NET Build - Bin Folder vs CodeBehind File

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Assume there is a asp.net 4.0 web application and it has a default.aspx and default.aspx.cs files in it. After I build the project, a dll that is named of the project created in the bin folder. So what the dll contains ? All code behind files compiled versions ?

If the aspx files still refers its CodeBehind file like below, then does the dll used for this aspx file or still code behind is valid to run the project ?

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3._Default" %>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this depends on your project type and your build options, web site and web application behave differently

Answer (score 5):

In a **Web Application**, all your C# code is contained within the DLLs in the bin directory.  There are a couple of exceptions, such as DLLs that you rely on that live in the GAC, for example.  Using a web application ( your question says this is what you are using ), you do not need to deploy your *.cs code behind files.

A **Web Site** is different.  Changes are detected and recompiled on the fly.  You'll need to include your C# files code-behind files when creating a Web Site type project.

[ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

A DLL is a library that contains code and data that can be used by more than one program at the same time:

[What is a DLL?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815065?wa=wsignin1.0)

[Code-behind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163675.aspx) refers to code for your ASP.NET page that is contained within a separate class file. This allows a clean separation of your HTML from your presentation logic:

[ASP.NET Code-Behind Model Overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303247)

Answer (score 0):

The code gets compiled into the assembly produced by your web project. You can change its name and default namespace as part of project options.

As I understood it, the ASPX file is only used IF the project is marked as being updatable, otherwise it is just a placeholder file.