# ASP.NET website - default namespace

Tags: asp.net

In Visual Studio you can set a default namespace for a VB.NET app using the following screen:

[image]

You can do the same for an Visual Studio project that is an ASP.NET web application.  It is not available for an ASP.NET website, why? I see this for a website:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Web Site projects are missing many features that Web Application Projects have.

See [ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application) for a detailed comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way ASP.NET Web Sites are distributed and compiled, there is no reason for a default namespace because each ASP.NET file is dynamically compiled and turned into its own DLL the first time the page is loaded (the "old way" of doing ASP.NET).

However, with a Web Application, a bunch of codebehind files (and potentially other code files) are precompiled into a single DLL, which then creates a situation where it is a Good Idea to put all of that into a single namespace.

You can think of it as a Web Site is a collection of Web Pages, but a Web Application is a unified whole.

Comment: Thanks.  You say: "However, with a Web Application, a bunch of codebehind file".  Websites have code behind files as well.

Comment: Right. With Web Sites, each is dynamically compiled into its own DLL. With Web Applications, a **bunch** are bundled together in one DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I am using websites and I needed a way to access the BundleConfig, IdentityConfig, and RouteConfig classes and modules from with in my Global.asax file. I was able to put these files into the "App_Code" folder which allows you to put namespaces around the classes and modules.

Here is an example:

```
Namespace TCEmpSite
    Public Module RouteConfig
        Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
            Dim settings As FriendlyUrlSettings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Then in the Global.asax file I was able to do this:

```
Private Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Code that runs on application startup
        TCEmpSite.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        TCEmpSite.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
        TCEmpSite.IdentityConfig.ConfigureIdentity()
    End Sub
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Website will not create a dll but web app will create. To create a dll for website,use web_deploy project.