# Left hanging on an MVC tutorial when it came to publishing my website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a beginner at ASP.NET and MVC. I came across this tutorial from w3 schools (they've never let me down before) : http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp
Things were going great until the last page of the demo leaves you high and dry as far as publishing the website you have just created. I followed the directions EXPLICITLY but my website won't pull up, I just get a blank page. PLEASE any help at all would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're going to need to provide more info about the site you are trying to publish to and what tools you are using.  Are you in Visual Studio, if so, which version.  Are you publishing to Azure? via FTP? Web Deploy?  There are lots of options, so more info will help.

Comment: Well, if you are a beginner at ASP.NET MVC the best resource for you is [official tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) probably.

Comment: @Bryan Lewis : I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2012. There's a link to download it on this page here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp

Comment: @Bryan Lewis : I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2012. There's a link to download it on this page here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp. I don't know if I'm not sure if I'm using Azure or not. I actually am running the website off of my local machine because I have installed Apache Web Server. This is literally my first attempt to publish a website. If you look at the last page of the tutorial that I used it uses generic sayings like "copy your website to an application folder on your server". Is that supposed to be in my wwwroot folder on my machine?

Comment: Also, I know that the basic setup of my machine works because I got noip set up for my computer and also set up a basic index.html and was able to browse to it by bringing up Google Chrome and navigating to my outside IP Address.

Comment: I've heard otherwise about that site, so this might be your first time :) That article states a need for "FTP" instead of "Publishing" but it's not mutually exclusive. In fact, you can [publish locally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14103211/304683) and even get a full understanding of "what to FTP" or "what to copy". Goes without saying you need to know what your hosting provider supports - specifically/obviously ASP.Net - I mention this because of your comment about "Apache" in your local machine. Visual Studio has its own web server for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be a direct answer to your question vis-a-vis the link you provided, I would suggest you start with a modern version of VS.  It will make things easier.  Get VS 2015 Community edition for free at: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

As far as running your site locally, VS can run the site in debug on IIS Express and it's all built in out of box without need for Apache.  It will simplify your setup and should run with a single click.

Comment: There is no problem running the web page in Visual Studio Web Developer 2012, I can do that right now. The problem I have is with what do I do to make the page run as a stand alone web page. Do I have to put a certain file in my wwwroot folder? If so, what is it? Is there a certain structure that I have to conform to in order for me to request the page via my noip url?