# Creating membership provider in ASP.NET Website Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have looked at some tutorials and they all seem to use Web Application Model for membership providers. How can I create membership in an existing website that uses Website model? Or is it not possible/not preferred?

Comment: Are you referring to legacy ASP.Net Website? http://stackoverflow.com/a/398049/296861

Comment: @Win yes. when you do File->New Web Site instead of File->New Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Membership is available long before Web Application.

However, you want to try [New ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) (updated version of legacy Membership Provider).

1. Follow the first half of Scott Hanselman's tutorial (second half is for MVC)
2. Follow [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile - Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) for legacy ASP.Net.

**Note:** I didn't really test New `ASP.NET Universal Providers` in ASP.Net Web Site, because all of our sites are Web Application.

If it new one doesn't work, you can follow through the step 2 all the way. Only different is that `New ASP.NET Universal Providers` uses Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks win for guidelines i will give it a try