# I can't find options for Select Master Page or Place code in separate file in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I installed VS 2012 on my work PC, and for the life of me when I go to add a new web form, I cannot see or find the 2 options for `Select Master Page` or `Place code in separate file`.

Any ideas on how i can find them?

Comment: What is the Visual Studio 2012 version you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have **web form with master page** in the add items?

Placing code in separate file is a different concept called `code-behind`.  You will have an `ASPX` file and a `cs` / `vb` file which handles the events.

**e.g.**

> Default.aspx
>   Default.aspx.cs

[image]

**EDIT**: Based on comment.

You may be using a `Web Site` on your laptop, but a `Web Application` in work.  See [Web Application Projects v's Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx).

Take a look at [ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application), this might also help in deciding which to use.  Generally, I always go for Web Application.

You can use VS to [convert from a Web Site to a Web Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but AFAIK, you can't do it the other way round unless you create a new project and copy across the relevant parts - which could be a big job depending on the size of the site.

Comment: I have that, web form with master page, but on my laptop (which has vs2012) gives me all those items and gives me the two options, and i was trying to understand why its not working like that on my work pc

Comment: ohhh, ok. I see what you are saying. Is there a way i convert it to a website? Everytime i go to create an app i always use Visual C#>Web>Asp.Net Empty web application. I do that as well on my laptop.

Comment: @Cwm, NP - I just added a part about the conversion.

Answer (score 9):

I've just been fooled by just that for the past hour.  What I've found is that the 'old' method of using the menu option 'Add web page using master' (or similar) has vanished, and been replaced by 'Content Page'.  When you select this, you're then given the option of choosing a master page.

Incidentally, I don't get the option of starting a web site project, which may be why I'm not seeing this either.

Comment: Same same ... changed, and been wondering what the heck and where do they hide things these days.

Comment: And why on earth don't Microsoft flag this up?

Comment: because they don't want us sheep to use dangerous outdated technologies like visual studio 2012 ? :)

Comment: Moo moo (or whatever it is sheep say).  I'm just trying to get my head round entity framework.  Imagine being married to Julia Lerman?