# ASP .NET Website; first load of every page is very slow

Tags: asp.net, performance

I'm facing with the following situation:
On an ASP .NET website(this is maybe important, it is not a web app. project, it is a website project in VS) the aspx pages load very slow for the first time; and the key is, that EVERY page is loading very slowly for the first time, not only the very first page after an app pool restart;
Of course I know that the app. pool is stopped after a certain amount of idle time, and after restarting the very first page load can be slow; but I think this is not the case in this site, since every page's first load is slow after deploying the website to IIS.
It seems that every page is compiled at the time when it is first loaded, don't know, if it's possible at all.

Any ideas, what can cause this, and how to avoid?

Comment: See [ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application). Your pages _are_ being compiled upon first visit.

Comment: Do you have heavy operations in your code behind? Each page needs to be compiled/executed. If you want to avoid this, you can use service such Pingdom to make regular request to your page and prevent AppDomain from recycling.