# Why does Visual Studio force to create solution file? How can I avoid solution files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a asp.net website and when I open it, Visual Studio asks me to create solution file every time. But I don't want the solution files at all. How can I create a website without a solution file? 
There are other related questions in stack overflow but they give workaround by creating the solution file. I don't want to create solution file.

Comment: Why do you want to not do a solution file?

Comment: I don't want an additional file in my project. I open the website from IIS in Visual Studio and solution (sln) file is no use to me. Do you think having sln will give me additional benefit? I don't want to add any additional projects in the site. It's just a simple website with couple of pages.

Comment: The solution file isn't _hurting_ anything. You can ignore it if you want.

Comment: According to this page the solution is required: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7.aspx

Comment: Perhaps your needs would be better served by right clicking on the solution file, clicking Properties, checking the Hidden attribute, and closing the Properties window.

Comment: That's kind of Ostrich Algorithm you're suggesting :) 
But the solution file will still be there. So, does this mean it's compulsory to have a solution file for any type of project while using visual studio?

Comment: @mason "Although a project must reside in a solution, you can create a solution that has no projects."

Comment: @BenAaronson Is a web site considered a project, even without a `.csproj` file? I guess so, at least for these purposes.

Comment: @mason Do web sites not have `.csproj` files? I may be thinking of a different project type then

Comment: @BenAaronson `Web Sites` do not have `.csproj` files, but `Web Applications` do.

Comment: @mason Ah, I stand corrected.

Comment: I'm still here guys ! :)

Comment: So does it mean there is no alternative to creating solution for website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `New Website` instead of `New Project -> New Web Application`, you can easily move the site's code files around. You don't need a solution file (although one will be generated in a separate location). You can ignore that solution file for the most part. I think that's as close as you can get to a "no solution" ASP.NET website.

Note that the New Website approach doesn't generate a project file (.csproj), which you may also want to get rid of if I'm following your line of reasoning correctly.

See [ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application) for a discussion of Web Site vs Web Application.

Comment: In conclusion, it seems solution file is necessary even if we create a website only as .NET uses it to manage the site as well as the projects that may be added later. Hence, it's not possible to have a website with just a list of files. There has to be a solution file or VS will attempt to create it if not present.