# What is the difference between ASP .NET Web Forms Applcation and ASP .NET Web Forms Site

Tags: asp.net

I need to write a simple app which will work in a cloud where I can store data about clients and it will be avaiable from Windows  and Android and I assume it has to be a website.

What is the difference between ASP .NET Web Forms Applcation and ASP .NET Web Forms Site? Which one should I use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: as for me this is almost the same

Comment: @a3code I added screenshots from Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2):

This has been explained in detail in the following question:
[ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application/398049#398049)

Also, you can check out the differences between the two here:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: While that link may provide an answer to the question, it would be ideal if you could provide a relevant summary, with proper attribution. Otherwise, your answer may turn invalid or useless if the link becomes broken or the page's content changes.

Comment: Totally agree, the link is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Web Form Site is nothing more than previously called Website projects where you work with webpages which is just small php like (with Razor/aspx) script files which render as html.
Webform is more like a component oriented framework. Web Form Site or WebSite should only be used for small projects or if the project needs to be compile in `C#/VB` both language. Also if you want to put your all source code in web-server then it can be used. On contrary with WebForm application you don't need to put code base files to run the projects - you'd be better off only putting scripting `.aspx` files.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I am little confused because I don't know which project template is the bet one. So which project template I should use if I want to create CRM that enables adding and viewing info about clients on Android Phone and Windows via browser?

Comment: Comparing one to another nothing says you can't do what you want with WebFormSite or WebForm. So to this point I guess its personal preference which template you'd like to work with. For me I like none of them now, I'm comfortable in MVC architecture more now. If your site requires to work in mobile and desktop browsers both I think you also should worry about what responsive css-framework you would choose for your site.

Comment: Is there a cloud that can just run my standard WinForms application and just show the client view of that application so no .NET Framework is needed? Like an illusion that .exe is run on clients computer but it's in the web?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question if your app is native or hybrid then you need REST(WebApi in .net world) which any app can access natively regardless of the device and will meet your needs of the "cloud".

If you what you want is a website instead that is "viewable" by mobile devices you may want to make your website "responsive" and you can look at various bootstraps templates that can help you with that.

Regarding your second question I think it has no bearing nor it will make any difference in creating a mobile app which project type you use.