# What template to use for new website in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm confused by the myriad of options for creating a new website in Visual Studio 2015.

In particular, I don't understand the difference between

- File > New... Website... ASP.NET Website (Razor v3) and
- File > New... Project... ASP.NET Web Application > ASP.NET 4.6.1 Templates > MVC 4

What I'd like is a website that works well with Entity Framework and provides scaffolding to quickly create data entry forms.

It seems MVC 4 provides this, but is there something similar for Razor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between the Web Application and the Website is that it will compile the application into a single DLL file at build time. In order to update the project it must be recompiled and the DLL file published for changes to occur.

Read more at [ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application) and [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx)