# Aspx CodeBehind can't get Text from Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am new to asp. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community. I created a new Website over "File>New>Website>Website for AspWebForms "

Now my problem is I am writing now in CodeBehind, in my About.aspx.cs. If I try to get text from a asp Textbox over `tb_bezeichnung.Text` it says it's not in context.

So after long search I figured out that i need a Designer.cs, I cant recreate it or have any options to Convert to WebForm.

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master"
         AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="About" %>
```

tb_bezeichnung is a Asp Textbox.

Project Explorer contents:

[image: Picture of Project Explorer]

[About.aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJehn.png)

[About.aspx.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzmfL.png)

Comment: Please also include the definition of `myTexbox` as in your file `About.aspx` (click [edit] and then add it into the question).

Comment: Check if the class name has the same name in the file of the inherit.

Comment: I think its typo :) you have `TextChanged` event for a `TextBox` and  there the `tb_bezeichnung` name is `tb_bezeichnung0` so changing this line will might solve your issue `string Test = tb_bezeichnung0.Text`.

Comment: please show  `About.aspx` script and code behind

Comment: Note that based on the above you don't "need" a `designer` file - you have what's known as an Asp.Net _web site project_. Designer files are used in Asp.Net _web application project_

Comment: I think it was typo and that designer files was missing. I solved it by creating a new Project as "WebForm" and put all code inside it q.q
i tried it before but i think the typo was all the fault.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to take the value of your textbox, after let's say a button click for an example?
Just create a Button and OnClick event and let's say add an Label in the design view, in the OnClick Method write:

in aspx file add:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click me !"  OnClick="Button1_Click" />    
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Code behind:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've started with a "Web Site" instead of a "Web Application".  A Web Site type uses older technology and is more difficult to maintain, I recommend starting over with a Web Application, which creates the designer files automatically.  See Here..

[ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application)