# Rider - equivalent settings for VS 'Website Project'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csproj, rider

I have forked a Visual Studio-made website on github and am trying to open it with JetBrains Rider. It has no .csproj file (but does use a .publishproj file - think this is Azure related). As such Rider finds no projects to run and I can't seem to set up a run configuration for the local web server.

[image: Run configs]

When I run it in VS I can hit F5 and the localhost webserver starts up and servs my browser the pages nicely. Anyone know how to setup the same in Rider for a ASP.NET Web Site ?

Cheers

EDIT: This is the root of the difference I'm seeing - Rider is fine with Web Apps that have .csproj files but can't seem to create run configs without

[ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application)

Comment: Try to create a new project from existing code. Usually there is that option.

Comment: That's a VS option right? In Rider you can Open or make a New solution. It does allow you to make a new ASP.NET WebApp but not a Website

Comment: Just a minute, my EAP has expired, need to re-install Rider for the 20th time.