# Implementing PostSharp with Asmx Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, postsharp

I'm currently trying to integrate postsharp with my asmx web service for the purpose of logging exceptions.

Here's my code for the Aspect perspective:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogPerformance : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        string test = "test";
        base.OnEntry(args);
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        string test = "test";
        base.OnExit(args);
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        string test = "test";
        base.OnException(args);
    }
}
```

while in my Service.cs class, i've the following web method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[SoapHeader("authentication")]
[LogPerformance]
public DataTable loginUser(string userName, string password)
{
    doStuff();
}
```

Coming straight to the point:

- Does postsharp support implementation with web methods? As in my case, 
  postSharp methods does not get called whenever the **web method** receives 
  a hit. (Yes i've added postsharp reference using Nuget and/or/plus manually added its dll as well) [This](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/1254-using-method-interception-with-postsharp-on-asmx-webservices) does 
  suggest a step towards the mentioned subject but i could not make anything 
  out of it.

It is important to note that the same **LogPerformance** Class runs smoothly when integrated with:

- Web API
- ASP.Net Web Application (MVC)
- Console Application

The problem is when i use it with .asmx web service. A little nudge towards the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all you need to make sure that PostSharp compiler executes when you build your project. Your project must have a *.csproj project file and this project file must contain an Import line with PostSharp.targets. In your build output you should see at least one message from PostSharp.

Comment: @alexD Thank you for your response, i just checked and its verified that my solution does not have .csproj file. Secondly in my build output, i do not see any message from post sharp. Can you please confirm of your product's support for .asmx services?

Comment: The .asmx are supported, but only in web application projects with *.csproj file.You need to convert your web site to web application, look for example at this blog post (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project/). After conversion you need to install PostSharp NuGet package into your project.

Comment: @AlexD Thank you again, your method worked in my case.

Comment: Great! I've added the complete answer for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *.asmx web-services are supported by PostSharp. However, you need to pay attention whether your ASP.NET project is a *Web Site* or a *Web Application* ([ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application)). Only *Web Application* projects are supported by PostSharp. For more information on compatibility you can also check [Requirements and Compatibility](http://doc.postsharp.net/requirements).

You can convert your *Web Site* project to *Web Application* project by following the guidelines from the blog post [Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project/). After the conversion you need to install PostSharp NuGet package into your project.