# 3 tier application in classic ASP.Net into multiple dlls

Tags: asp.net

We have developed a 3 tier web application in classic ASP.Net, but non-MVC architecture.
The challenge is, the source ( all the app_code and .cs pages) is compiled into a single assembly (DLL), so for every change the entire source gets recompiled & new dll is shared with the client.

Is there a way where we can break this into smaller services/separate dlls for each cs page and recompile only the service/app_code class which has been modified ? How all these smaller assemblies can be assembled/integrated to run the application ?

Any ideas/solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The "web-site" project type (compared with "web-application" project type) allows you to compile each page with code-behind into separate DLL. more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application)