# How to prevent the visual studio from automatic publishing of the source code, when choosing 'publishing on web deploy' option?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish

I want to publish my web project to the IIS server, but my .cs files from my controller folder (and other places) are copied too. when publishing, I ticked the "only copy needed files " and "precompile before publish" checkboxes. How to prevent it?

Comment: [ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application)

Comment: @Steve web application of course