# Visual Studio 2019 not debugging all my code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, pdb-files, compiled

I am working on an ASP.Net application using VB.Net with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8.4.  While investigating an issue with breakpoints, I noticed that what Build Solution is creating under Temporary ASP.Net Files\root folder is not what is being created under the Temporary ASP.Net Files\vs folder when I debug.  Files are missing. I deleted ALL files and folders under Temporary ASP.Net Files before Building and Debugging for this post.

The files under root are

```
    Directory of c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8a321177\e9179428

02/03/2021  09:55 AM    <DIR>          .
02/03/2021  09:55 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/03/2021  09:25 AM                 0 045bmzzz.tmp
02/03/2021  09:25 AM                 0 3n4hgsyj.tmp
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            11,785 4itj5afk.cmdline
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 4itj5afk.err
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            12,763 4itj5afk.out
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             3,548 4itj5afk.res
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 4itj5afk.tmp
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            11,426 4o5rx2zg.cmdline
02/03/2021  09:29 AM                 0 4o5rx2zg.err
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            12,009 4o5rx2zg.out
02/03/2021  09:29 AM                 0 4o5rx2zg.tmp
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               370 admin.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            11,785 ah1d3brg.cmdline
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 ah1d3brg.err
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            12,368 ah1d3brg.out
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             6,427 ah1d3brg.res
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 ah1d3brg.tmp
02/03/2021  09:25 AM               175 App_Code.compiled
02/03/2021  09:25 AM             3,613 App_Code.fyvt0kvv.0.vb
02/03/2021  09:25 AM            52,401 App_Code.fyvt0kvv.1.vb
02/03/2021  09:25 AM               725 App_Code.fyvt0kvv.2.vb
02/03/2021  09:25 AM            28,160 App_Code.fyvt0kvv.dll
02/03/2021  09:25 AM            54,784 App_Code.fyvt0kvv.pdb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               260 App_LocalResources.members.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               688 App_LocalResources.members.cdcab7d2.wts9ewqw.0.cs
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            23,040 App_LocalResources.members.cdcab7d2.wts9ewqw.dll
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             7,680 App_LocalResources.members.cdcab7d2.wts9ewqw.pdb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            92,609 App_Web_4itj5afk.0.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             3,558 App_Web_4itj5afk.1.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           140,284 App_Web_4itj5afk.10.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            72,051 App_Web_4itj5afk.11.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           528,801 App_Web_4itj5afk.12.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            27,886 App_Web_4itj5afk.13.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             2,088 App_Web_4itj5afk.14.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           156,906 App_Web_4itj5afk.2.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             8,661 App_Web_4itj5afk.3.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           178,619 App_Web_4itj5afk.4.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            10,319 App_Web_4itj5afk.5.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            89,227 App_Web_4itj5afk.6.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             3,673 App_Web_4itj5afk.7.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            91,800 App_Web_4itj5afk.8.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             2,812 App_Web_4itj5afk.9.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           273,408 App_Web_4itj5afk.dll
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           419,328 App_Web_4itj5afk.pdb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            93,907 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.0.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             2,297 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.1.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            94,378 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.10.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             6,555 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.11.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             1,846 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.12.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            95,632 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.2.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             6,538 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.3.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM           142,995 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.4.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             8,330 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.5.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            82,541 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.6.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             8,381 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.7.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM           175,243 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.8.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            39,405 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.9.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM           168,960 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.dll
02/03/2021  09:29 AM           220,672 App_Web_4o5rx2zg.pdb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           132,960 App_Web_ah1d3brg.0.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            12,457 App_Web_ah1d3brg.1.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            88,742 App_Web_ah1d3brg.10.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             6,126 App_Web_ah1d3brg.11.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           253,279 App_Web_ah1d3brg.12.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            36,080 App_Web_ah1d3brg.13.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             2,090 App_Web_ah1d3brg.14.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           150,333 App_Web_ah1d3brg.2.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            15,124 App_Web_ah1d3brg.3.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           226,166 App_Web_ah1d3brg.4.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            22,967 App_Web_ah1d3brg.5.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            95,432 App_Web_ah1d3brg.6.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             2,842 App_Web_ah1d3brg.7.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           249,706 App_Web_ah1d3brg.8.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            12,785 App_Web_ah1d3brg.9.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           262,656 App_Web_ah1d3brg.dll
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           378,368 App_Web_ah1d3brg.pdb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           150,964 App_Web_etqshhml.0.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            57,398 App_Web_etqshhml.1.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            93,018 App_Web_etqshhml.2.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             3,008 App_Web_etqshhml.3.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           169,984 App_Web_etqshhml.4.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             5,344 App_Web_etqshhml.5.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            91,316 App_Web_etqshhml.6.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             3,557 App_Web_etqshhml.7.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             1,650 App_Web_etqshhml.8.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           123,392 App_Web_etqshhml.dll
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           165,376 App_Web_etqshhml.pdb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           103,073 App_Web_pzaw0i5l.0.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             3,539 App_Web_pzaw0i5l.1.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           675,001 App_Web_pzaw0i5l.2.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            83,606 App_Web_pzaw0i5l.3.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           192,319 App_Web_pzaw0i5l.4.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            27,962 App_Web_pzaw0i5l.5.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             1,464 App_Web_pzaw0i5l.6.vb
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           234,496 App_Web_pzaw0i5l.dll
02/03/2021  09:28 AM           333,312 App_Web_pzaw0i5l.pdb
02/03/2021  09:24 AM    <DIR>          assembly
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               366 dc1a.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               366 dc1m.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               382 dc1m_cap.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               390 dc1m_check.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               406 dc1m_check_cap.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               362 dc2.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               366 dc2a.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               382 dc2a_cap.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               406 dc2a_cap_check.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               390 dc2a_check.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               366 dc2m.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               390 dc2m_check.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               362 dc3.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               386 dc3_check.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               362 dc4.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            40,919 dc4.aspx.28424a96_CBMResult.ccu
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               359 dc4.aspx.28424a96_CBMResult.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               390 dc4m_check.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               410 dc4m_check_edit.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               386 dc4_excel.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               362 dc5.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            10,955 etqshhml.cmdline
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 etqshhml.err
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            11,538 etqshhml.out
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 etqshhml.tmp
02/03/2021  09:24 AM    <DIR>          hash
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               329 home.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               353 pdf_opener.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:28 AM               410 pdf_regenerator.aspx.28424a96.compiled
02/03/2021  09:25 AM            10,027 pjyfbvpq.cmdline
02/03/2021  09:25 AM                 0 pjyfbvpq.err
02/03/2021  09:25 AM            10,610 pjyfbvpq.out
02/03/2021  09:25 AM                 0 pjyfbvpq.tmp
02/03/2021  09:24 AM               116 preStartInitList.web
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            10,844 pzaw0i5l.cmdline
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 pzaw0i5l.err
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            11,427 pzaw0i5l.out
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            11,351 pzaw0i5l.res
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 pzaw0i5l.tmp
02/03/2021  09:28 AM    <DIR>          ResX
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               345 rpt_cfpt.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               345 rpt_main.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               345 rpt_sfpt.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               357 rpt_summary.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:25 AM    <DIR>          Sources_App_Code
02/03/2021  09:28 AM             9,518 wv5g0baw.cmdline
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 wv5g0baw.err
02/03/2021  09:28 AM            10,068 wv5g0baw.out
02/03/2021  09:28 AM                 0 wv5g0baw.tmp
```

The files under vs are:

```
Directory of c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\3bb81b17\b159d10f

02/03/2021  10:02 AM    <DIR>          .
02/03/2021  10:02 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               175 App_Code.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             3,613 App_Code.pn0ojzoe.0.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            52,401 App_Code.pn0ojzoe.1.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               725 App_Code.pn0ojzoe.2.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            28,160 App_Code.pn0ojzoe.dll
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            52,736 App_Code.pn0ojzoe.pdb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            94,378 App_Web_s1csb3a0.0.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             6,555 App_Web_s1csb3a0.1.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            95,632 App_Web_s1csb3a0.10.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             6,538 App_Web_s1csb3a0.11.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             1,846 App_Web_s1csb3a0.12.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM           142,995 App_Web_s1csb3a0.2.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             8,330 App_Web_s1csb3a0.3.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM           175,243 App_Web_s1csb3a0.4.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            39,405 App_Web_s1csb3a0.5.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            82,541 App_Web_s1csb3a0.6.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             8,381 App_Web_s1csb3a0.7.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            93,907 App_Web_s1csb3a0.8.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM             2,297 App_Web_s1csb3a0.9.vb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM           168,960 App_Web_s1csb3a0.dll
02/03/2021  09:29 AM           220,672 App_Web_s1csb3a0.pdb
02/03/2021  09:29 AM    <DIR>          assembly
02/03/2021  09:29 AM    <DIR>          hash
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               329 home.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               353 pdf_opener.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               116 preStartInitList.web
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               345 rpt_cfpt.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               345 rpt_main.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               345 rpt_sfpt.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM               357 rpt_summary.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            10,154 rvzhftzj.cmdline
02/03/2021  09:29 AM                 0 rvzhftzj.err
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            10,697 rvzhftzj.out
02/03/2021  09:29 AM                 0 rvzhftzj.tmp
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            11,540 s1csb3a0.cmdline
02/03/2021  09:29 AM                 0 s1csb3a0.err
02/03/2021  09:29 AM            12,083 s1csb3a0.out
02/03/2021  09:29 AM                 0 s1csb3a0.tmp
'''
For example lets take home.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled and dc4.aspx.28424a96.compiled.  home.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled and its referenced .dll and the related .pdb exist under root and vs. dc4.aspx.28424a96.compiled and its referenced .dll and the related .pdb exist under root but NOT under vs.

There is one difference between these .aspx files in the solution.  home.aspx is located under the root of the one project in the solution.  dc4.aspx exists under a folder called Members under the root of the one project in the solution.  All the other missing .aspx files are also located under the Members folder.

I believe this is what is causing the issue I am having setting breakpoints (Breakpoint will not be hit.  No symbols loaded for document) in dc4.aspx or any of the other missing .aspx files under vs.

I've been trying to figure this out for 3 days.  I've read just about every thread on the breakpoint error.  I've found almost nothing about the missing files.

Let me know if I can provide anymore info.  This is my first post on stackoverflow, so if I have violated any etiquette rules, please accept my apologies.

Thanks!
```

Comment: You can open csproj file, then check if the Members/dc4.aspx is included which is like : `<Content Include="Members/dc4.aspx"/>`, and if it doesn’t work, could you provide the contents about Members/dc4.aspx in csproj?

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT This is VB.Net not C#.  There is no csproj file.

Comment: My mistake, it is the `vbproj` file. I correct my commet. And could you provide related contents about `Members/dc4.aspx` in `vbproj`?

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT That's the next mystery, there is no vbproj file.  The issue is not just Members/dc4.aspx, it is every .aspx file under the Members folder.  A little more info, this solution was working just fine late last year.  It is a legacy application, so it doesn't get changed much.  The only thing that has occurred is that I have applied at least two updates to VS 2019 since the last time I opened the solution.  NuGet was also affected, it wouldn't display the installed apps in the solution, but when trying to reinstall them, NuGet said they were already installed.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you create a asp net website project rather than a asp net framework web application project? That website project does not have any output files stored under project root folder, and it does not contain any proj file. And website project is not good enough and you might have any errors or trouble if you use it and it is only lightweight and convenient. It is not a good choice for large projects. And you should use asp net net framework web application project. [Here's a comparison of the two projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application).

Comment: And webiste project cannot send your new build changes to the IIS in time, and that is a difference. So if you close vs, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, build website project several times,clean IIS, all do not help, you should create a asp net web application project and then migrate the old content into the new one. We do not have your project sample to test it. Also, this kind of problem is random, very occasional, even if temporarily fixed, will inevitably be encountered in the subsequent process. The best way is to use asp net web application.

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT - It is a website project.  It was originally written in VS 2005 and then converted to 2010, 2017 and 2019.  What I have done to resolve this issue is to create an empty web application project, copy all the files from the website project to the web application project and then use the convert to web application capability in VS 2019.  This appears to have resolved the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Be glad to know that you have solved the issue. Since one of my tips help you handle the issue, I have added an answer here and you could [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) since it works so that it could help other community members search and handle similar issues. And it is kind of you to do that. Anyway, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an answer here:

**Since** the website is from the old **VS2005**, create an empty web application project, copy all the files from the website project to the web application project and then use the convert to web application capability in **VS2019**.