ASP.NET MasterPage can't access it's own Label from code behind
I have a weird issue where I have a MasterPage, inside it a simple navbar with labels. For example I have the following label in the Site.Master:
<asp:Label ID="TestLabel" runat="server" CssClass="badge bg-danger"/>

But when I try to access it from the Page_Load of the MasterPage by saying:
TestLabel.Text = "test text"

Then I simply get the error saying "The name 'LostCount' does not exist in the current context". I'm not quite sure why, because I did similar MasterPages before, where the same thing happens - label in MasterPage markup, set value on Page_Load - and it works just fine.
Just to clarify, I am trying to access this label from the Page_Load of the MasterPage itself - not the content page. The MasterPage should have no issue accessing it's own element, right?

Okay, as I was just about to send this question, I have found the cause. The top markup of the MasterPage included the .cs file as CodeBehind.
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="ProjectName.SiteMaster" %>

Changing it to CodeFile solves the issue, now I can access the Label properly.
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="ProjectName.SiteMaster" %>


A big change to make then? That assumes the page must have been imported from some other project, and a project that was not a "application", but was a older web site project.  GREAT caution is required here, but CodeFile means  you are working on a "web site" as opposed to a "web site application". That's ok, but you NOW VERY MUCH need to figure out why and how a web page was created the wrong way. This suggests that you are opening the project 2 different ways - VERY bad to do so. So, if you have a "web site", then you use file->open web site. If application, then use file->open project.

Interestingly, no. The whole project was just recently created as a new ASP.NET solution. But I checked one of our older websites and saw the difference (codefile vs codebehind) so I tried it and it works. Not sure why Visual Studio created it this way or if this is some difference in the .NET versions. But at least it works this way.

it works as it supposed to. If you create a asp.net .framework web site (which I do NOT recommend), then your page directives are going to be CodeFile, and IIS is doing the code compile for you (which you REALLY do not want). then there is the 2nd type of project called a asp.net web site "application" (the important word here is "application"). So, keep in mind the VAST difference between the 2 types of projects, with rather similar names. So, if you correctly created the right project type, then when you add a new page to the site, then you REALLY hope that you see CodeBehind being used

If you created the wrong project type (the older legacy web site project), then you get the older and VERY difficult to work with CodeFile setup. You want to fix this right now, and make sure  you created a asp.net .framework "application", and then you have a valid project file (.sln), and when you add pages to the site, you see CodeBehind page directive. If that's not what you see, then fix this now before it is too late, and you go down the road of enjoying world poverty.

I see. Just as you said, we might be using the project types where IIS is doing the compilation.
Can I do some reading on why is this not recommended?

Well, it not so much the "end of the world" kind of deal breaker here. However, having a valid .sln project file allows you to have mutliple projects in one, allows you to include other complex class libraries as a project. So, at build time, those external projects also build for you. And what happens if your code is using Roslyn syntax (which is rather nice for strings, or in-line SQL etc., and many other features). Now, if you using a "web site", then IIS does the code compile (and often the hosting plan does not have Roslyn compiler features installed - so, you deploy and code breaks.

And your referances are far better managed with a .sln project. So, you can for example clear out the .bin folder, and during build, all referaced assemblies and nuget packages will be copied into the bin folder. With a web site, then nuget assemblies are actaully placed in the .bin folder, so you can't clean it out - also makes Git-hub less then ideal. I mean, the simple answer is that a .net Visual Studio project with a valid .sln file is a much nicer setup, and a "web site only" doe snot have a valid project .sln file, so you lose any and all advantages of a .sln file.

I mean, it not really rocket science that you are bulding + compiling on your developer computer, and then when you deploy, some other computer (the web server) is to now compile your code, and thus you hope on a wing and a prayer that the server going to be setup exactly as your developer computer when you do the compile? (that's not acceptable to me). To be fair, web sites were often deployed this way, and that's only a testimony as to how well the .net ecosystem was built and how rock solid it is. And I prefer to deploy without source code on the web site - it far more secure.

the pro's and con's of either choice is outline here: (but, for me, it not a close choice). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application
